# Powering a tablet from 5V, how to regulate current draw?

Tags: usb, current-limiting, step-down

I'm making a circuit that controls a 24V led strip, but it has some extra peripherals too, mainly some buttons to interface with. However, I also want to attach a micro usb cable, so it will be able to charge a tablet. A quick rundown of the relevant circuit parts: 24V in goes towards the 24V of the LED strip and a 5V buck converter (1.5A continuous, 3A short term). Buck converter supplies 5V input for an ESP32, the tablet and some other peripherals. (The image shows the full circuit diagram, the usb connection is on the right hand side. Relais is present but as an example, so the specs may not correspond to what is required).

[image: LED strip circuit]

Below is the cheap cable I cut up to use for this. Since I want to simply connect the Vin (red) and gnd (blue) cables directly to their respective lines in the circuit, I am not fully sure if the tablet will overdraw the available current in the circuit (i.e., would it be able to draw the full 500mA, or even more?). I added this later in the design, so I did not test it on the full circuit, however I blew up some transistors during testing yesterday (which weren't even rated up to 500mA and I attached a powerbank instead of a tablet so no surprises there), but it made me want to be sure about it being safe, before I go on accidentally frying my entire circuit when it's connected.

EDIT: this is Buck converter I am using:
https://www.tinytronics.nl/shop/en/power/voltage-converters/buck-(step-down)-converters/dc-dc-step-down-buck-converter-1.5a-5v-output

[image: USB cable to be used]

Comment: Welcome! Are you aware of how power negotiations over USB work?

Comment: No, not really. I found that "dumb" usb cables (which mine is, I believe, since the  the D+ and D- are not connected), generally means the device only draws a small amount of current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not fully sure if the tablet will overdraw the available current in the circuit (i.e., would it be able to draw the full 500mA, or even more?).

The schematic in the question shows a relay controlled by a GPIO on the ESP32 to switch `GND` to the USB connector. Using a relay means:

1. No current limiting.
2. May be some contact bounce which could affect the USB powered device.

On a sample of microcontroller development boards which allow supplying 5 V when acting as a host, rather then mechanical relays a *USB power switch* IC is used. E.g. the [Tiva™ C Series TM4C1294 Connected LaunchPad Evaluation Kit EK-TM4C1294XL User's Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/spmu365) shows a [TPS2052B](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS2052B) being used with the `EN2` enable signal controlled by the on-board microcontroller:

[image]

Where the TPS2052B provides protection:

> When the output load exceeds the current-limit threshold or a short is present, the device **limits the output current** to a safe level by switching into a constant-current mode, pulling the overcurrent (OCx) logic output low. When continuous heavy overloads and short circuits increase the power dissipation in the switch, causing the junction temperature to rise, a **thermal protection circuit** shuts off the switch to prevent damage.

If your tablet can charge sufficiently quickly using using 5 V at 500 mA, which any USB 2.0 host should supply without negotiation, then consider changing the relay to a USB power switch ID.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is a wall mounted tablet, so charging speed is relatively unimportant, so long as it charges. Unfortunately I couldn't find any power switch IC's like the TPS2052B that I can order, or buy somewhere close by. I looked around a bit via results and stuff, and was wondering if would also work if I'd put a current limiting diode before the USB output?

Comment: Not sure what is the concern here.  Any USB 2.0 device should not pull more then 500mA @ 5V w/o negotiations.  There are exceptions like Apple and HP devices.  But I believe those devices need to see certain voltages on unloaded D+ and D- line from the power source.  If you don't provide that, then I believe the USB 2.0 peripheral is obliged to only pull 500mA or less.

Comment: @st2000 I think the concern was in the case of fault condition, e.g. a short of VBUS to GND in a USB cable, rather than a USB 2.0 compliant peripheral.

Comment: I see. Perhaps the buck power supply can be chosen to have a current limiting feature.  However that would likely reset the all other processors/devices on the 5V line.

Comment: @st2000 with the shoddy usb cable I was using, that was indeed the main concern, although I also fell into a rabbit hole of trying to figure out if I could limit the current to the usb somehow. 500mA would never really be required and could mean for example the LED strip wouldn't get enough power.
Anyhow I have decided to hopefully solve it by adding a buck converter with a max current output of ~600mA only on the usb line.